# Sending HTTP/2 request via Socket in Java

Tags: java, http2

I'd need to send an HTTP/2 request via a TCP socket from my Java classes. I've adapter a piece of code which works for plain HTTP/1.1. However it does not output any response nor error code when using HTTP/2.

Can you see anything wrong in it? The server I'm trying to reach it's on https://localhost:8443

```
Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 8443);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
pw.print("GET / HTTP/2.0\r\n");
pw.print("Host: localhost:8443\r\n\r\n");
pw.flush();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String t;
while((t = br.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(t);
br.close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is that really a valid HTTP/2 request?

Comment: I've assembled it from Firefox debugger. I assume it is, but I've included http/2 group in the question to have a confirm of it

Answer (score 6):

That will not work.

[HTTP/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) is a binary protocol, not a textual protocol, so in order to use a raw socket you have to generate the proper bytes that form a HTTP/2 request.

This is quite complicated as it requires that you implement [HPACK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541) to compress the headers, so you will be far better off using a Java library that does HTTP/2 for you, with a higher level API (rather than using raw sockets).

[Disclaimer: I'm the HTTP/2 implementer in [Jetty]](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Jetty offers a low-level HTTP/2 client that allows you to deal with HTTP/2 frames, and a high-level HTTP client that can send generic HTTP request using the HTTP/2 format.

For the first you can find an example here: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.18.v20190429/jetty-alpn/jetty-alpn-java-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/java/client/JDK9HTTP2ClientTest.java

For the second one there is this section of the documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/http-client-transport.html#_http_2_transport

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!